# What should 'RS' be set to in this awk command

Tags: linux, awk

I'm using awk to strip useful infos from log files. This is what my log file looks like:

```
2016-02-19 20:18:46,861 115971,100126017,524,523,1,[144115198332971054]
2016-02-19 20:18:46,874 95496,100126019,5,5,0,[]
2016-02-19 20:18:46,883 115974,100126025,57,57,0,[]
2016-02-19 20:18:46,891 115975,100126026,4,4,0,[]
2016-02-19 20:18:46,918 115976,100126027,122,122,0,[]
2016-02-19 20:18:47,688 115978,100126029,11656,11641,15,[144115198334490817,144115197319238988,144115197291063350,144115198332904743,144115197318718547,144115197319714394,144115197306930902,144115197250548791,144115198320676757,14411519
7253880518,144115197289305237,144115198083289344,144115197319697491,144115198273784435,144115198081583082]
2016-02-19 20:18:47,731 99590,100126032,12,12,0,[]
2016-02-19 20:18:47,832 115982,100126034,1397,1396,1,[144115198273784435]
2016-02-19 20:18:47,849 106705,100126035,31,31,0,[]
2016-02-19 20:18:47,860 107469,100126036,16,16,0,[]
2016-02-19 20:18:47,927 115983,100126037,824,824,0,[]
2016-02-19 20:18:47,985 115985,100126039,564,564,0,[]
2016-02-19 20:18:48,048 115986,100126040,338,338,0,[]
2016-02-19 20:18:48,108 115987,100126041,259,259,0,[]
2016-02-19 20:18:48,187 115989,100126043,693,692,1,[144115198273784435]
```

I use `","` for the `FS` variable; I need the complete content between the `[]` square brackets, so I tried to set `RS` as `"]"`:

```
awk  'BEGIN { FS=","; RS="]";}  { print $2 ,$3, $6 ,$7}' removed-apply.log.2016-02-19
```

but the result is wrong:

```
861 115971 100126017 1 [144115198332971054]
874 95496 100126019 0 []
883 115974 100126025 0 []
891 115975 100126026 0 []
918 115976 100126027 0 []
688 115978 100126029 15 [144115198334490817
731 99590 100126032 0 []
832 115982 100126034 1 [144115198273784435]
849 106705 100126035 0 []
860 107469 100126036 0 []
927 115983 100126037 0 []
985 115985 100126039 0 []
048 115986 100126040 0 []
108 115987 100126041 0 []
187 115989 100126043 1 [144115198273784435]
```

Seems the `RS` is still the line break.

Comment: tks for ur advice  :D

Comment: tnx for taking the advice ;-) Glad you got a solution. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: On second thought, you can get away with a *single* input field-separator regex (specified via option `-F`, which translates to variable `FS`):

```
awk -F ',\\[?|\\]' '{ print $2 ,$3, $6 ,$7 }' removed-apply.log.2016-02-19
```

<sup>Note the need to *double* `\` instances to produce the character following them as a *literal* in the context of a *regex*. E.g,  `\\[` is turned into literal `\[` by `awk`'s initial *string* parsing, which *regex* parsing then sees as `\[`, resulting in interpretation as *literal* `[`. In short: *string* `,\\[?|\\]` results in *regex* `,\[?|\]`.</sup>

---

**Original answer** (as accepted):

Your input is still clearly *line-oriented*, so there's no reason to change `RS`, the input-record separator.

Instead, parse each line in *two* steps:

- Use `FS` to *initially* break the input into *2* fields: before `[`, and between `[...]`.

  - Note: The strange-looking regular expression used below, `[][]`, is a character set( `[...]`) containing 2 literal characters, `]` and `[`; it is conceptually equivalent to `\[|\]`.
- Then, use `split()` to split each resulting field by `,` into subfields stored in *arrays*:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { FS="[][]" } # split into $1 (before "[") and $2 (between "[...]")
  { 
    split($1, fa1, ",") # split $1 into subfields by "," and store in array fa1
    split($2, fa2, ",") # split $2 into subfields by "," and store in array fa2
    # Output fields of interest
    print fa1[2], fa1[3], fa2[1], fa2[2]
  }' removed-apply.log.2016-02-19
```

---

Comment: the square bracket "  [  ] " is a character class , so "[][]" means either [ or ] can be matched ...  i didn't figure it out until i reviewed the regular expression grammar ... tks for your reply ! it saved me ~ :D

Comment: @JasonHuang: Yes, `[][]` is very odd-looking; glad you figured it out. Also note the simpler solution that I've since added.

Answer (score 1):

Using "]" as the RS seems to be a step in the wrong direction.  (How would you tell the difference between an input file consisting of "[abc]" and one consisting of "[abc"?)

Assuming the text you want is between square brackets on the same line, the following would be able to handle the type of input you describe:

```
grep '\[.*\]' | sed -e 's/^[^[]*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/'
```

You might need to tweak this depending on the details of your requirements.  It would also be easy to translate this into awk.

If your requirements are more complex than the above can handle, then please elaborate them.